# Vue.js show dynamic images is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm a beginner at vue.js and I'm trying to show images dynamically but I'm having an issue with displaying  them dynamically, if I change them manually it works I found many similar problems with a bit of difference none of them have helped me

this is my structure:

```
-src
  --assets
    ---pizza
      ----pizza-1.jpg
      ----pizza-2.jpg
    ---hamburger
      ----hamburger-1.jpg
      ----hamburger-2.jpg
    ---french-fries
      ----french-fries-1.jpg
      ----french-fries-2.jpg
 --components
 --DBjson
   ---main.json
```

I'm trying to make this loop

```
`<div class="holder" v-for="restaurant in restaurants">
  <img :src="getImage(restaurant.name, restaurant.mainImage)"/>
 </div>

  export default {
name: "restaurant",
data() {
    return {
        restInfo: this.$attrs.restData,
    };
},
methods: {
    getImage(folderName, imageName) {
        let image = require.context("@/assets/");
        return image("./" + folderName + "/" + imageName);
    },
 },
};`
```

my JSON file

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "pizza",
    "price": "$10",
    "mainImage": "pizza-1.jpg",
    "images": ["pizza-2.jpg", "pizza-1.jpg"],
},
```

Comment: In `<template>` you're calling `getImage` but in controller you define `getImageUrl`.

Comment: I made  a typo while I was typing it

Comment: Can you try with `image("/" + folderName + "/" + imageName)` ? Without `.` dot inside `image()`

Answer (score 1):

getImage should require and return the image using the image's full relative filepath

### Vue 2.x

```js
getImage(folderName, imageName) {
  return require(`@/assets/${folderName}/${imageName}`)
}
```

### Vue 3.x + Vite

Vite as far as I know can't handle '@' alias for this particular task so be sure to set your path accordingly

```js
getImage(folderName, imageName) {
  return new URL(`../assets/${folderName}/${imageName}`, import.meta.url).href;
}
```

Comment: I made it this way, it didn't work

Comment: are you using Vue 2 or Vue 3?

Comment: I’m using Vue 3

Comment: I've updated my answer with the Vue 3 solution

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work , bro thanks for your efforts I really got you struggling with my issues, I’m gonna drop this project out cause I’m stuck with this problem